# Connect to MongoDB with authorization

Tags: windows, mongodb, authentication, mongo-shell

I have this below user created in MongoDB

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5368247553e1d8650fdee0d1"),
    "user" : "userName",
    "pwd" : "3d8540469xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx28fbf8b76",
    "roles" : [ 
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am trying to connect to my remote MongoDB instance

```
>mongo --host 10.0.0.1 --port 27017 --username username --password password
```

I get bellow error

```
errmsg: auth failed 
code: 18
exception: login failed
```

I am not sure what is wrong. If i disable authorization in my config file and restart my replica sets instances, I can connect correctly.

[image: Error screenshot]

**Solution:**

Working with the below user roles
[image: Working user roles]

Comment: @whoeverDownvoted, please feel free to share what do you think is wrong in this question, so that I can correct my question.

Comment: what happens if you connect to admin DB specifically (and not test)?  Add the word admin to the end of your mongo command line.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
mongo -u yourUser -p yourPwd --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Answer (score 0):

use

mongo --port 27017 -u username -p pas